# How to open vs code in a new window when i commit with git bash outside and inside of vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

I want to know if there any way to open a new window of vs code when i decide to commit with git.

**First situation:**

I'm  ready to commit and i open git bash to type:

```
git status
git add .
git commit
```

When i send the last command, vs code are opened to type mi message on him. But i already have one window of vs code open and i want the git bash open vs code in a new window, is this possible?

**Second situation**

I'm inside vs code and i'm ready to commit. I open git bash terminal inside vs code to commit. Same history:

```
git status
git add .
git commit
```

And when i send the last command vs code open a new tag, no a new window, to put the message. I want the editor open a new window to put the message, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git config --global -e` will open the git config in an editor

```
[core]
    editor = code --wait -n
```

add to the core.editor -n which according to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) forces a new window